# What is the "correct" way to call transactionally safe from one EAR file to another using Spring?

Tags: java, spring, transactions, ear, distributed-transactions

I have two spring applications A and B, each within an individual EAR file. Now I want to call from A to B and vice versa, maybe even A -> B -> A or more.

The calls have to be **transactionally safe**.

What is the recommended approach?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to keep this safe is to use JTA transactions, managed by the container.  Spring supports these via its `JtaTransactionManager`, so you can write your transactional logic the same as any other transactions in Spring. All data sources must be managed by the container, not by the applications.

Comment: That provided; But what technology can I use to do the actual call? RMI doesn't work, because it is not transactional, JmsInvokerProxyFactoryBean is not transactional as well, other remoting technologies have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to make a synchronous transactional -- with two face commit -- call from one EAR to another is to use remote EJBs :(

If it is possible in your case I would rather go for an asynchronous call using JMS, the sending of the message will be coupled with your transaction but the receiver won't be able to rollback your transaction as it would be possible with a remote EJB call.

Comment: is this definitely the case, or is it more of a hunch?

Comment: @Mauli It is as far as I know... You may have a look at http://www.atomikos.com/ but if you already have an EJB container I would use it...